# How to add App.Config file in Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I want to store the connection string and some parameters in app.config file which we generaly do for windows aplication but I can't find app.config file for console application. So how should I use this file, how to add this file or there is some other work arroud for the same functionality. I am working in console application

Comment: Do accept the answer below as its the correct answer for your question / edit your question in case you need any more information.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Try adding a new Application Configuration file by right clicking on the console project rather than on the solution.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Right click on application->Go to Add->you will see the exact picture What i have attached here->Pick the Application Config File.[image]

Comment: it should reside next to the exe ? It doesn't affect my application

Comment: I see there is MyApplication.exe.config

Comment: thanks for this comment. the MyApp.exe.config needs to be next to the exe

Comment: Add reference to it, then add using System.Configuration; using System.Collections.Specialized; Then add something like string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("connectionString");

Answer (score 8):

Well, the other answers might have worked for others, but for me, adding a settings file to the project's properties solved the problem - it actually serialized the settings (which are editable via a visual designer) to the config file for me. So this way, the config file approach showed in the other answers here didn't work for me, but instead creating a settings file did work.

The steps are:

Project (not solution) > Add > New Item > Settings File

[image: Adding Settings File]

In addition, you might want to have your settings available in your code with strongly-typed values. I did the following:

1. renamed the settings file to something useful - mine was "Settings.settings"
2. **moved this file to the "Project > Properties" section**
3. double-clicked the settings file icon
4. In the designer, added settings keys and values
5. Viola! You have the settings available in your app, with strongly-typed values!

So, now I could access my settings like this (from my console app):

```
bool boolSetting = Properties.Settings.Default.is_debug_mode;
```

After compilation, I found that these settings are stored automatically in a file named "AssemblyName.exe.config", alongside the console binary itself in the `Debug` directory.

So, I think this is a cleaner, and more flexible way of creating and managing the app's config file.

**NOTE**: Am running Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, and am building a .NET 3.5 console app.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

source: http://blog.nickgravelyn.com/2010/02/visual-studio-2010-xna-and-you/

Comment: I can't use Online Templates for adding this file, I don't have permissions as well as any option for this.Also I know how to use online templates but I don't have any option for adding this file

Comment: @Nits - This is not an add-in, it's been in visual studio since day 1.  It has nothing to do with the fact you are using a console app. The answer is correct. +1

Comment: I don't have Online Template option in my VS, I am sure about this.

Comment: Online Templates isn't selected in that screenshot, it just looks a bit like it is. What's actually selected is "Visual C# Items", with the lighter gray background.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone using VS2017 above and if you are not seeing the option highlighted in image [Application Config File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtFsJ.png)
Then most probably you have not installed .net desktop development tools.

*The application configuration file template* comes from .net desktop development workload, so you need to make sure you've installed it in VS2019/VS2022.(Go tools=>get tools and features=>make sure you have .net desktop development workload checked. Or Use Visual Studio Installer to install the required package.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, just open the Project tab and press Add Form (Windows Forms) then search for config and you will find app.config